# React Native: How to redirect

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native and I just don't get how react-navigation works. I've already spend multiple work days and tried different variants, but I don't even get the examples from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ to work.

My project is created with `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`, like it's described on the [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

So I went back to my last working point (without routing).

This is my File Structure:

```
root
- src
- - screens
- - - LoginScreen.js
- - - HomeScreen.js
- App.js
```

In my App.js I just perform an easy call:

```
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
export default LoginScreen;
```

This is a simplified version of my LoginScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    AppRegistry,
    Button,
    ReactNative,
} from 'react-native';

/**
 * Actual View
 */
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // some values
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <View style={[styles.containerOne]}>/>
                // Some Input fields
                <Button
                    onPress={this.loginButtonOnPress.bind(this)}
                    title="Login"
                    style={[styles.loginButton]}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    loginButtonOnPress() {
        // Validation with fetch
    }
}

export default LoginScreen;

/**
 * Style
 */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerOne: {
        marginTop: -160,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
    loginButton: {
        color: 'blue',
        marginTop: 10,
    }
});
```

The LoginScreen.js should be the first displayed page. I want to load my HomeScreen.js file when loginbuttonOnPress get called. How am I supposed to do that? I've already found something like

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});
```

But I don't get this to work, too.

I'm thankfull for every help I can get.

Comment: have you try : 
`const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
navigate('Home')` in the `loginButtonOnPress()` function ?

Comment: I did, but I get an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: I just get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')` displayed on my device. Seems like the error is somewhere in `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation`. I can't copy the whole stack trace because of i don't get the error displayed in the Expo XDE Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press login button then go to HomeScreen.

```
render() {
    return (
            <View style={[styles.containerOne]}>/>
            // Some Input fields
            <Button
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home'))}
                title="Login"
                style={[styles.loginButton]}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

You can try it work

App.js

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
},{ swipeEnabled: false }
```

);

```
export default SimpleApp
```

Comment: This won't work eather. Which imports would I need for this? I have "import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';"

Comment: can ı see other files ? (App.js vs ) @Tekk

Comment: You can find my whole Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/TekkCraft/react_native)

Comment: Cool, I'm one step closer to the success. The LoginScreen get loaded when I start the app. But which import do I need for `navigation.navigate`?

Comment: you dont need anything . you can use this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')

Comment: Yes, this works! Is there a way that I can't click back when I'm at the HomeScreen? Right now, when I press Login, I got redirected to the HomeScreen, but there is this little arrow on the top left corner to go back to LoginScreen.

Comment: yo can add home screen ->

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null
  }

Comment: Ok, the arrow is gone, but I can still swipe back. Is it possible to set this Root as the new root or something like that?

Comment: I got it to work with `static navigationOptions = {gesturesEnabled: false}` in the HomeScreen Class.

Comment: i like it your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside you function

```
loginButtonOnPress() {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
}
```

Comment: This won't work. I don't even get an error when I press the button. There is just nothing happening.